# Cannot list the data in my Aandroid application from Mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Am new in Android development. I trying to do database CRUD  operation in my android application.
                    I can successfully insert the data to the mysql.Am using PHP and JSON parsing for it.When the data inserted into database, the next activity should be listing the data.The problem is no data is coming into my listing activity. only the Activity is coming without data. kindly help me .

Here in this code , am trying to display three data , "name, price, description. The PHP file will 
                                retrieve the data from the database mysql  , and convert the strings into JSon objects. Then my javacode will call the json class and list the data. I can successfully insert the data to the mysql.Am using PHP and JSON parsing for it.When the data inserted into database, the next activity should be listing the data.The problem is no data is coming into my listing activity. only the Activity is coming without data. 
          Also  my java code for the listing products is

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

```
                                // Progress Dialog
                                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                                // Creating JSON Parser object
                                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

                                // url to get all products list
                                private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/get_all_products.php";

                                // JSON Node names
                                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
                                private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
                                private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
                                private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

                                // products JSONArray
                                JSONArray products = null;

                                @Override
                                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

                                    // Hashmap for ListView
                                    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                                    // Loading products in Background Thread
                                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

                                    // Get listview
                                    ListView lv = getListView();

                                    // on seleting single product
                                    // launching Edit Product Screen
                                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                                            // getting values from selected ListItem
                                            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                                                    .toString();

                                            // Starting new intent
                                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    EditProductActivity.class);
                                            // sending pid to next activity
                                            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                                            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                                            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                                // Response from Edit Product Activity
                                @Override
                                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                                    // if result code 100
                                    if (resultCode == 100) {
                                        // if result code 100 is received
                                        // means user edited/deleted product
                                        // reload this screen again
                                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }

                                }

                                /**
                                 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
                                 * */
                                class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                                    /**
                                     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                                     * */
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                                        super.onPreExecute();
                                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
                                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                                        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                                        pDialog.show();
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * getting All products from url
                                     * */
                                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                                        // Building Parameters
                                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                        // getting JSON string from URL
                                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                                        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                                        try {
                                            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                                            if (success == 1) {
                                                // products found
                                                // Getting Array of Products
                                                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                                                // looping through All Products
                                                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                                                    // creating new HashMap
                                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                                                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                                                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                                    productsList.add(map);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                // no products found
                                                // Launch Add New product Activity
                                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                                        NewProductActivity.class);
                                                // Closing all previous activities
                                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                                startActivity(i);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        return null;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                                     * **/
                                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                                        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        // updating UI from Background Thread
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                /**
                                                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                                                 * */
                                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                                                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                                                TAG_NAME},
                                                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                                                // updating listview
                                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }

                                }

                                }


                                Here in this code , am trying to display three data , "name, price, description. The PHP file will 
                                retrieve the data from the database mysql  , and convert the strings into JSon objects. Then my javacode will call the json class and list the data. I can successfully insert the data to the mysql.Am using PHP and JSON parsing for it.When the data inserted into database, the next activity should be listing the data.The problem is no data is coming into my listing activity. only the Activity is coming without data. kindly help me .


                 My JSON class for parsing or converting is as follows

                            This is my JSON parsing code .In this code first i created a function for get json from the url . then the code for making http request for GET and POST method by using if , else statement . In else method i put the code for get method . i converted it into json object , and the above android code will call it and display it in the activity..
                        I used a JSON Parser class to get JSON from URL. This class supports two http request methods GET and POST to get json from url.
                    As we are getting the JSON by making HTTP call, I am adding a Async method to make http calls on background thread. Add the follwing method in your main activity class

                                public JSONParser() {

                                    }

                                    // function get json from url
                                    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
                                    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                            List<NameValuePair> params) {

                                        // Making HTTP request
                                        try {

                                            // check for request method
                                            if(method == "POST"){
                                                // request method is POST
                                                // defaultHttpClient
                                                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                                                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                                is = httpEntity.getContent();

                                            }else if(method == "GET"){
                                                // request method is GET
                                                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                                                url += "?" + paramString;
                                                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                                                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                                            }          

                                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        try {
                                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                            String line = null;
                                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                                            }
                                            is.close();
                                            json = sb.toString();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                                        }

                                        // try parse the string to a JSON object
                                         try {
                    if(isValidJson(json))
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  Log.v("json String","Result => "+json);
               }

                                        // return JSON String
                                        return jObj;

                                    }
                                }    




This is my JSON parsing code .In this code first i created a function for get json from the url . then the code for making http request for GET and POST method by using if , else statement . In else method i put the code for get method . i converted it into json object , and the above android code will call it and display it in the activity..
                    I used a JSON Parser class to get JSON from URL. This class supports two http request methods GET and POST to get json from url.
                As we are getting the JSON by making HTTP call, I am adding a Async method to make http calls on background thread. 
            I used a JSON Parser class to get JSON from URL. This class supports two http request methods GET and POST to get json from url.
                As we are getting the JSON by making HTTP call, I am adding a Async method to make http calls on background thread.      


    Since nothing is displayed in my activity. i have the following error in my logcat.
            my logcat error is displayed below  .
```

Since nothing is displayed in my activity. i have the following error in my logcat.
                my logcat error is displayed below
                 .
Since nothing is displayed in my activity. i have the following error in my logcat.
                my logcat error is displayed below

```
   03-10 03:49:54.491: W/System.err(1559): org.json.JSONException: No value for products
                03-10 03:49:54.491: W/System.err(1559):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
                03-10 03:49:54.508: I/Choreographer(1559): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                03-10 03:49:54.528: W/System.err(1559):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
                03-10 03:49:54.558: W/System.err(1559):     at com.example.sampleapp2.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:141)
                03-10 03:49:54.618: W/System.err(1559):     at com.example.sampleapp2.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
                03-10 03:49:54.668: W/System.err(1559):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                03-10 03:49:54.698: W/System.err(1559):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                03-10 03:49:54.718: W/System.err(1559):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                03-10 03:49:54.748: W/System.err(1559):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                03-10 03:49:54.788: W/System.err(1559):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                03-10 03:49:54.898: I/Choreographer(1559): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                03-10 03:49:54.958: W/System.err(1559):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                03-10 03:49:55.038: I/Choreographer(1559): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.a`enter code here`
                03-10 03:49:55.168: I/Choreographer(1559): Skipped 212 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                03-10 03:49:55.218: I/Choreographer(1559): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot list the data in my android application from Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291968/cannot-list-the-data-in-my-android-application-from-mysql)

Comment: Check your logcat you may find your response json data at line `  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());`

Comment: @ Blacktiger,,I dont get you. can you explain little more detail

Comment: I dont find it in my logcat

Comment: try to print `json.toString()` into textview

Answer (score 0):

check JSonObject has products's key value.

```
 03-10 03:49:54.491: W/System.err(1559): org.json.JSONException: No value for products
```

this error show's JSONobject not have products key value.

Comment: @ Amadas How can we check whether JSONObject has product key value?

Comment: you used this code 'Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());'. you can show your log.

Comment: @ Amadas , i dont find it in my logcat. that message is not coming

Comment: yes that message is in my logcat. what can we do to display to my activity

Comment: @NeenuJose What code is AllProductActivity.java in line 141? I think that's error is 'int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);' or 'products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);'